# TeXLive - no  latex binary after installation

Tags: texlive, ubuntu

I have installed TeXLive 2012 on Ubuntu 12.04 via `install-tl` and chose a minimal set of packages, so that I could later `tlmgr install ...` everything I would need with dependencies automatically resolved. During installation I chose a subdirectory of the `home` directory (user install) and not `/usr/...`

After installation I've updated the path env. var. so the command `tlmgr` works, however `latex` or `pdflatex` commands don't exist. I've tried `tlmgr install latex` and it downloaded and installed some 3 packages, but still no `latex` command in bash (other tex binaries like `bibtex` exist in `/texlive/bin/i386-linux/`, but no `latex`).

Comment: did you make sure to update your `PATH` variable?

Comment: Maybe the format wasn't generated properly on installing. Does `tlmgr generate fmtutil --rebuild-sys` help? Does calling `tex -fmt pdflatex` work, i.e. produce what you would expect `pdflatex` to produce?

Comment: @cmhughes, @UlrichSchwartz: Thank you, it seem I had to install `latex-bin` as @mpg suggested, installing only package `latex` was not enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install package `latex-bin` for the latex command.

Comment: Thank you, that did it. Btw. do you know how to make dependency-resolving work? For example on the minimal pkg configuration I've installed package `tkz-berge` for graph drawing and it complained about missing sty files. Then I had to google each sty file to see in which package was it and install the package manually via tlmgr. Is this the common way or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Resolving dependencies and their dependencies is very hard to do automatically. I'd say it is probably the cont one will have to pay for the small installations and trying to add stuff on the go.

Comment: We (TeX Live Team) never guaranteed proper dependencies between packages, but we *try* to keep collection dependencies halfway uptodate. That means if you install a collection then most things will work. But if you decide to install package per package you are on your own, and will remain, as we have no way to automatically generate these dependencies.